# Is onDestroy always called when android destroys activity to save memory but does not kill App?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to use `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to monitor how many activities are there in the back-stack. Can I increment/decrement counter in onCreate/onDestroy to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is onDestroy always called when android destroys activity to save memory?

Yes

**Documentation:**

The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called `finish()` on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()` method.

> I want to use Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to monitor how
>   many activities are there in the back-stack. Can I increment/decrement
>   counter in onCreate/onDestroy to handle this?

Better to counter in the `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods, onCreate() doesn't guarantee visibility. For example if somehow something stopped `onStart()` from happening.

Comment: Better to counter in the stop start pause. This counter will not show home many activities are the in the back-stack. It will show is the application on the foreground or not.

Comment: No reason to be better, it's more clear when implemented in start stop. You could use `pause()`, but like I said `start` and `stop` works just fine.  if `start()` is followed by a `stop()` in stead of a `resume()` the count will still be correct.  Remember `pause()` comes after `resume()`.

Comment: But the counter will be always 0, when the application is on background. But it is not what i need. I want to define if any activity is running on background or foreground(doesn't matter) and get the current activity class.

Answer (score 3):

onDestroy is **NOT** guaranteed to be called every time an activity is destroyed.

If the user clicks back to destroy it, onDestroy will be called.
If the user swipes the application from the recent app menu, onDestroy will NOT be called.
If the application crashes, it's undetermined if it'll be called (from my experience, it isn't called).

Comment: This should be a comment because it doesn't answer the actual question, but I agree he should consider this.   Just to add, it is next to impossible to know if the app is force killed except in the  Google Developer console.

Answer (score 1):

onDestroy() is the final method that is called on an Activity instance before it’s destroyed and completely removed from memory. In extreme situations Android may kill the application process that is hosting the Activity, which will result in OnDestroy not being invoked. Apparently most of the Activities will not implement this method because most clean up and shut down has been done in the OnPause and OnStop methods.
For more details please visit Android Developers Portal.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html "Android Developers")